# Return first emitted result from list of observables or return error if empty

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a `List<Observable<?>>` and I want to get the first item emitted by any of these (running sequentially) or return error from last observable if all returned error or custom error if all were empty (which I can do with `.switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(RuntimeException())))`.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOfObservables)
        .take(1)
        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(RuntimeException()))
```

This code handles getting only first emitted value and returning an error if all observables were empty but don't handle error case. Any ideas how I can solve that part?

Comment: If the snippet you posted is solving the first part of the problem, I am not sure I understand the problem at all - since there is no `flatMap`/`concatMap` in there I don't see how this would emit _items_ at all - it should always emit `listOfObservables.get(0)`...?

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want

```
Observable
  .fromIterable(listOfObservables)
  .concatMapDelayError(i -> i)
  .take(1)
  .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(new RuntimeException()))
```

`concatMapDelayError` will process observables sequentially as requested and delay errors till the end, so if every observable is an error you will get `CompositeException` with all exceptions aggregated.